# I cannot understand the reason about what is Dbset?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

The problem is that i cannot understand what is the meaning of the Dbset used in it.
Is it a way to initialize a list or is it a part of Entity Framework??

Comment: You should do some googling before you start posting questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read Microsofts [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696460(v=vs.113).aspx)?

> "A DbSet represents the collection of all entities in the context, or that can be queried from the database, of a given type."

An easy way to think about it is that a DbSet represents a **table** in your database. It is almost always used together with something called a [DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx), which essentially is a representation of a database connection.

**Example code that shows how several DbSets are used together with a DbContext:**

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserGroup
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } 
}

public class ExampleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 
    public DbSet<UserGroup> UserGroups { get; set; } 
}
```

Please refer to [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) tutorial on how to get started with Entity Framework.

Comment: what sort of table?? 
created by me or it is virtually created by the frame work??

Comment: Entity Framework uses something that is called [Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx) which you can use to create a database and its tables.

Comment: means we have to use dbset whenever working with the Entity framework?

Comment: I would say so, yes. If you got any more questions, please feel free to create new ones. If you're happy with my answer, please mark it as accepted so that other people can refer to this question in the future.

I have also edited my answer to include a link  to a great tutorial for learning Entity Framework.